# Using statement in C# without implementing Dispose Method

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, using

I am trying to understand using block in C#. Can I create a custom object inside Using statement like the below which doesn't implement the IDisposable interface?

```
Class A
{
}

using(A a = new A())
{
}
```

It gives me error saying "Error 1   'ConsoleApplication1.A': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'"

How to correct this error? I do not want to do Class A : IDisposable

Any other way? Or it is a mandatory requirement that we need to implement IDisposable Dispose method in these kind of custom objects which we use inside using block?

EDIT: I am NOT expecting the definition that is there in the MSDN and thousands of websites. I am just trying to understand this error and also the rectification

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't want to use IDisposable? Maybe something better could be found.

Comment: @antiduh: Well let me rephrase my words for you. What is the meaning of that error "Convertible"

Answer (score 12):

Using blocks are syntactic sugar and only work for IDisposable objects.

The following using statement:

```
using (A a = new A()) {
// do stuff
}
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
A a = null;

try {
  a = new A();
  // do stuff
} 
finally {
  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, a))  
    a.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Why 2 calls to new A?

Comment: You should just leave `a = new A();` since variable `a` already exists

Comment: whoops, you are right.. and it seems to have been fixed up by some editors (thank you!)

Comment: @syazdani: This I know 3 years back and my question is not that. My question is completely different from what you have understood

Comment: @Divine, then I am really not sure what you are asking. using only works with objects that implement the IDisposable interface. That is the sole purpose of it, so to directly answer the questions: yes, you *must* implement IDisposable for the using statement to work. Choosing to implement IDisposable depends on whether you need to free resources immediately (like Files, Brushes, Mutexes, Semaphores, etc.) in your class. If your class does not implement IDisposable, you don't use using and let the garbage collector dispose of your class eventually.

Comment: @syazdani: Thank you, but what is that error "Convertible" I din't quite understand what it means. Could you please help me udnerstand? I was expecting "You should implement IDisposable in objects when you use USING". But error says different thing. Why the heck the error message is not friendly?

Comment: All "implied convertible" means is that the runtime should be able to cast a given object to a given type and get a meaningful result (in this case, casting A to IDisposable). In some situations, the compiler can check for this during compile time and give you an error if it is not possible (as it is doing for you because A does not implement IDisposable). Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of using is to create the equivalent of a try block with a call to Dispose in finally. If there is no Dispose method, there is no point to the using statement.